# PendingIntent.getBroadcast returns existing PendingIntent

Tags: android

I am creating a notification with a custom view, containing two buttons (yes/no). A click on these buttons will launch a PendingIntent, which will then proceed depending on the button clicked.
But PendingIntent.getBroadcast() always returns the first Intent (so that the BroadcastReceiver, which is called by the PendingIntent always thinks the first declared button "no" is clicked), which is propably due to missing Flags.

How to fix this? Do I need another BroadcastReceiver?

```
// create notification with custom view and two buttons
Intent buttonNoReceiver = new Intent(context, NotificationAfterReceiver.class);
buttonNoReceiver.putExtra(AppUtil.EXTRAS_EVENT_ID, event.getEventID());
buttonNoReceiver.putExtra(EXTRAS_BUTTON, "no");
PendingIntent pendingNoIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, event.getEventID(), buttonNoReceiver, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_no, pendingNoIntent);

Intent buttonYesReceiver = new Intent(context, NotificationAfterReceiver.class);
buttonYesReceiver.putExtra(AppUtil.EXTRAS_EVENT_ID, event.getEventID());
buttonYesReceiver.putExtra(EXTRAS_BUTTON, "yes");
PendingIntent pendingYesIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, event.getEventID(), buttonYesReceiver, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_yes, pendingYesIntent);
```

**NotificationAfterReceiver**

```
public class NotificationAfterReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String button = null;

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            button = extras.getString(NotificationUtil.EXTRAS_BUTTON);
        }

        if (button.equals("yes")) {
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_EVENTS_FULFILLED, 1);
            Log.i("NotificationAfterReceiver", "button yes");
        } else if (button.equals("no")) {
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_EVENTS_FULFILLED, 0);
            Log.i("NotificationAfterReceiver", "button no");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use different `requestCode` when calling getBroadcast()

Comment: What code should I use? I guess the default one is 1, but this will cause the same issue. Using a random number does not seem to be a very good solution..?

Comment: use 0 for "no" PendingIntent and 1 for "yes" PendingIntent

Comment: Won't this cause issues with notifications created by other events at the same time?

Comment: so use any unique requestCode, for example by incrementing an int value each time you call getBroadcast()

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a proper answer, a possible solution for making a `PendingIntent` unique, would be to use the current time, as in:

```
PendingIntent uniquePendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
```